# Why does my registry reading program fail?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, winapi, registry

[Regedit Screenshot http://i54.tinypic.com/3503vi8.jpg](http://i54.tinypic.com/3503vi8.jpg)

Now, this code:

```
HKEY hKey;
LONG regOpenCriss = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
char mydata[2000] = {'\0'};
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
DWORD dataLength = sizeof(mydata);
LPVOID messagecaliss;
GetLastError();
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL, GetLastError(), NULL,(LPTSTR) &messagecaliss, 0, NULL );

if (regOpenCriss == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "Test2", 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&mydata, &dataLength); //change the key you want to read
    printf("%s\n", mydata);
    system("PAUSE");
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
else
    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCTSTR)messagecaliss,"ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
printf("%s\t\n", mydata);
std::string FullPath(mydata,dataLength-1);
printf("%s\n", FullPath);
std::string FileName = GetFileNameFromPath(mydata);
printf("%s\n", FileName);
system("PAUSE");
```

The function GetFilenameFromPath is defined as:

```
std::string GetFileNameFromPath (std::string str) {
size_t found;
found=str.find_last_of("/\\");
return str.substr(found+1);}
```

When I call RegQueryValueEx with "QKSMTPServer3" as the second parameter, here is the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\QK SMTP Server 3\QKSmtpServer3.exe
Press any key to continue . . .
C:\Program Files (x86)\QK SMTP Server 3\QKSmtpServer3.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\QK SMTP Server 3\QKSmtpServer3.exe
QKSmtpServer3.exe
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Which is what I want. Now, when I call RegQueryValueEx with "Test2", I get:

```
C:\Test.exe
Press any key to continue . . .
C:\Test.exe
```

and the program crashes. Any ideas why??

Thank you very much

Comment: the function GetFileNameFromPath is taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code is not exception safe. If `std::string`'s member functions throw `std::bad_alloc`, you will leak a handle (the `HKEY`).
2. Check for error return codes and `GetLastError` for a more specific reason why your code is failing.
3. `printf("%s\n", FullPath);` should not compile, much less run. Are you sure it's not `printf("%s\n", FullPath.c_str());`?
4. Rather than a fixed size buffer, you should use `std::vector`. If you know that you're always going to be getting a file name, you should use `MAX_PATH` as your buffer size.
5. This code fails if Unicode characters are involved at all. Consider switching everything over to `wchar_t` instead.
6. `char mydata[2000] = {'\0'};` <-- Why `{'\0'}` instead of just `""` or `{}`?
7. You're not doing anything with the return code of `GetLastError();`
8. If there's no `\` or `/` in the string, `GetFileNameFromPath` will fail because `std::string::find` will return `string.npos`.
9. `system("PAUSE");` should really be replaced with `std::cin.get();` instead.

Comment: Hey, I added the .c_str() part and it worked. thank you very much. I don't understand #1 though.

Comment: @Jack: 1. A prime reason to not use `cstdio` -- my guess is that you're using an implementation where the first member of `std::string` is a pointer to the string itself, but which uses the small string optimization. 2. If an exception is thrown, your code never gets to the `RegCloseKey` call, so you leak the handle. Better to handle closing of the handle using an RAII class.